# XModule ditribution not found when running edx Studio

Tags: edx, openedx

I'm having a problem connection to edx Studio. When I run paver devstack studio I get this error

```
xmodule_assets common/static/xmodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/bin/xmodule_assets", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3084, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3097, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 651, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 952, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'XModule==0.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application




Captured Task Output:
---------------------


---> pavelib.assets.update_assets
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
python manage.py lms --settings=devstack preprocess_assets lms/static/sass/*.scss lms/static/themed_sass
python manage.py cms --settings=devstack preprocess_assets cms/static/sass/*.scss cms/static/themed_sass
xmodule_assets common/static/xmodule


Build failed running pavelib.assets.update_assets: Subprocess return code: 1
```

I thought I could install `XModule` with `pip install` but it turned out it's not a package as pip gave me this error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement XModule (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for XModule
```

Can anybody provide a proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would install XModule during the ansible managed steps. Those also take care of running all the pip installs for you.

If you really want to install the XModule library manually, you can use the `edx-platform/requirements/edx/local.txt` file.

Make sure you are in the edxapp environment. `sudo su edxapp` in a regular devstack should suffice, and then run `pip install -r requirements/edx/local.txt`

Comment: does that affects the others files or the other appliacations  ? I don't want to lose my work

Comment: Running the ansible playbook definitely affects your files. Running the pip install on the local.txt requirements file will only affect your virtualenv.

A consequence of this, is that the next time you run paver it will notice you changed something and it will try to make sure all the dependencies are ok. You should not lose you work, but you should definitely commit your changes into the git repo before trying this.

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting this error `error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Open_edX.egg-info/requires.txt'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform`

Comment: You should run as the edxapp user and inside the edxapp virtualenv. Run `sudo su edxapp` first. If after running this your prompt is not at `edxapp@localhost:~/edx-platform$` then your devstack probably was not installed correctly and the `local_dev` role was not run in the machine.